# Why can't we set a derived type for generic parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

In the below code

```
    public class CustomValidator<T>
    {
        // some code 
    }

    public abstract class Parent
    {
        public CustomValidator<Parent> Validator { get; protected set; }
    }

    public class Child : Parent
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Child()
        {
            Validator = new CustomValidator<Child>();
            // Doesn't work, cannot cast implicitly 
        }
    }
```

Since we can assign child to a parent,
why can't we set `CustomValidator<Child>` for a property of type `CustomValidator<Parent>`?

Comment: Because not all classes derived from Parent are going to be Child types, which means that other code might add something else to this validator, deriving from Parent, that is not a Child.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to leverage [covariance in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) introducing covariant interface, if your code allows it:

```
public interface ICustomValidator<out T> // Your new interface
{
    // some code 
}

public class CustomValidator< T>:ICustomValidator<T>
{
    // some code 
}

public abstract class Parent
{
    // Change property to your new interface
    public ICustomValidator<Parent> Validator { get; protected set; }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Child()
    {
        Validator = new CustomValidator<Child>();
    }
}
```

If you can't make your `ICustomValidator` interface(via marking the generic parameter with [`out`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier) keyword) covariant then as [@Michael Randall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1612975/michael-randall) said in comments 
`CustomValidator<Parent> != CustomValidator<Child>`